# Sphinx - sort by date and not by unix timestamp

Tags: sphinx

I need to view my results sorted by only the date part of the unix timestamp. I already have a datetime field in my database which I am converting to unixtimestamp for using with sphinx.

Sample Code In .conf file

```
SELECT id, deleted, posts, createdOn, publish, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(createdOn) as date1 , thread_title, first_post \
            FROM posts 

sql_attr_timestamp  = date1
```

Thanking you
Imran

Answer (score 1):

Sorting can be done using SetSortMode function:

```
$cl->SetSortMode ( SPH_SORT_ATTR_ASC, "date1" );
```

To sort by descending order use SPH_SORT_ATTR_DESC.